# How to get the current state of a $scope variable in AngularJS in a callback function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have a problem using a service/factory for a REST-interface and accessing the current data of the $scope variable in the callback function of the create method:

```
controllers.controller('ResourceAddCtrl', ['$scope', ... 'Resource','ResourceComb',
        function($scope, ...) {
            ...
            $scope.selectedEntryId = {};
            $scope.resource = new Resource();
            $scope.addResource = function(){
                $scope.resource.$create(function(response){
                    var id = response.id;
                    console.log($scope.selectedEntryId);
                    //ResourceComb.$create({res_id : id, rescomb_id : $scope.selectedEntryId},function(){});

                }); 
            };
        }]);
```

The problem is that `$scope.selectedEntryId` is always its initial value in the callback method although it is used whith ng-model in the html code and the value gets perfectly updated cause {{selectedEntryId}} produces the expected output when typing a number in a bindet input field.
Anyone an idea where my mistake is or how -i could solve the problem?

Comment: Can you post your HTML/template where you bind to `selectedEntryId`? Is the ng-model that sets `selectedEntryId` in a child scope of `$scope`?

Comment: You create a new resource but never give it any data. Check the request that's sent. Need to see html for the rest of the problems

Comment: The relevant HTML-src is the following  ` selectedEntryId` gets the id of a selected Combobox value:

`<select class="form-control" id="selectedEntryId" ng-model="selectedEntryId">

    <option ng-repeat="entry in entries" value="{{entry.id}}" >{{entry.name}}</option>
   </select>`

The case is that I want to use the selectedEntryId when the create-method successed which is possible with a callback as you can find in the angular documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too obvious to fix your problem, but it looks to me like you need to **set** the value on the scope once it has been returned.

```
// fwiw I'd prob. make the default a string
$scope.selectedEntryId = '';
$scope.resource = new Resource();
$scope.addResource = function(){
  $scope.resource.$create(function(response){
    // Set the ID on the scope
    $scope.selectedEntryId = response.id;
    // This is trivial now, but it will be the correct value
    console.log($scope.selectedEntryId);
    // ...and the HTML should automatically update itself, as well.
  }); 
};
```

Comment: sure seems to me the resource needs scope data before anything gets sent to server ... am I missing something?

Comment: It's possible, but it depends on what the `create` action does. If it just creates a blank resource, then it doesn't need any data. It would take in undefined, create the blank resource, and return the ID.

Comment: I guess, have never create blanks myself, seems strange to populate a db with blanks

Comment: Ha. I don't disagree with you. This does seem just too durn obvious to be the answer, but, hey, maybe it is :)

Comment: Well no the Problem is not how to get the returned data from the Server when the create successed. It is true the server returns an ´id` in the `Response` which I need to use later. But getting this id  works without Problem so I reduced the code.
 The problem is that I need to compare in this callback later the returned id and the `selectedEntryId` which will is changed by the user over the view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption that `Resource` is an ngResource, in which case, the function you're passing to `$create` is **not** the callback.

From the docs:

> - HTTP GET "class" actions: `Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])`
> - non-GET "class" actions: `Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])`
> - non-GET instance actions: `instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])`
>
> [AngularJS $resource Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

So in your code, you're actually passing `[parameters]`, not `[success]` - therefore the call is not made yet when the function runs and so `selectedEntryId` is its initial value.

Given that, give the following a try:

```
$scope.addResource = function(){
     $scope.resource.$create(null, function(response){
        var id = response.id;
        console.log($scope.selectedEntryId);
        //ResourceComb.$create({res_id : id, rescomb_id : $scope.selectedEntryId},function(){});

     }); 
};
```

Comment: Yes your assumption was correct. Resource is defined as follows:

`services.factory('Resource', ['$resource',
 function($resource){
  return $resource('resources/:id', {id:'@id'}, {
   query: {
    method:'GET', 
    url:'resources',
    isArray:false},
   update: {
    method: 'PUT', 
    transformRequest: function(data, headersGetter){
     delete data['id'];
     return angular.toJson(data);
    }
   },
   create: {method: 'POST'},
   delete: {method: 'DELETE'}
  });
 }]);`

Comment: But your solution also doesn't work. Looking in the console when clicking on a button which calls the `addResource()` method the success callback is executed cause changing the line `console.log($scope.selectedEntryId);` to `console.log('id:' + angular.toJson($scope.selectedEntryId));` indicates it is executed but the value of selectedEntryId is still its initial value.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the real problem is different. I tried a new simple example ( [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/nGR5CLHmx1l9eus4Z9Xb?p=preview)
) and found out that the reason must be something with ngInclude. I did not expect that this would have an effect: see this example:
changing in the main controller the model always updates in the one direction, but the other way round changing in the included page the controller variable x is not updated.